# Are there other methods to prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Let $ x>0 $ and $ y>0 $ be two reals such that
$$x+y=1$$
Prove that
$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N) $$
$$(1+\frac{1}{x^n})(1+\frac{1}{y^n})\ge (1+2^n)^2$$

I proved it by using the fact that the function $$x\mapsto \ln(1+\frac{1}{x^n})$$
is convex at $ (0,1).$

I would like if there are other methods.
Thanks in advance. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are several alternative proofs here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h303969p1644184

Comment: Thank you very much for these two methods.